# How do I formalize this proof? "Prove that if $x\ne 1$ then there is a real number $y$ such that $\frac{y+1}{y-2} = x$"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

Consider trivial problem:

> Prove that if $x ≠ 1$ then there is a real number $y$ such that $\dfrac{y+1}{y-2} = x$

Let's solve for y

$$\frac{y+1}{y-2} = x$$
$$y+1 = (y-2)x$$
$$y+1 = yx - 2x$$
$$y - yx = - 2x - 1 $$
$$y(1-x) = - 2x - 1 $$
$$y = \frac{- 2x - 1}{1-x}$$

Now, although it is obvious that if $x ≠ 1$ then $y$ is defined, but how do I express it formally? I believe that something like "It can be seen that $y$ is defined for any $x$, provided that $x ≠1$ $\Box$" Won't be a rigorous conclusion.

I want to write *formal* proof of the conjecture above (including all the necessary steps), how should I write it?

Comment: If ypu want a formal proof, you'll need to have some formal axioms for the real numbers ... and presumably one of those axioms will be that every non-zero number has a multiplicative inverse

Comment: You only need a rather trivial though very important axiom or assumption: if $\;c\neq0\;$ , then the linear equation $\;cx=a\;$ has **the** unique solution $\;x=\frac ac\;$ . This is based on the principle that if we have an equality and we perform a *legal* mathematical operation on both sides of it, the equality remains being an equality.

Comment: @DonAntonio, in other words, after solving for $y$, I mention this axiom, show that if x ≠ 1 then denominator (in our case $1-x$) doesn't equal to zero, and this would conclude the proof?

Comment: @Nelver Please read my answer below.

Comment: Use the intermediate value theorem on the open interval (-1,2) ?

Answer (score 1):

When solving an equation you are actually assuming that such a y exists (which is what you wanted to prove!). In order to prove that a solution y to $\frac{y+1}{y-2}=x$ exists for all $x\neq 1$ you can simply start by setting $y=\frac{-2x-1}{1-x}$, and then show that this y actually solves the equation, which is essentially doing your calculations in reverse.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, it is one step before the last one who needs the reminder, meaning: after you get $\;(1-x)y=-2x-1\;$ , then you bring up that principle (or axiom): "we can now divide both sides by $\;1-x\;$ **if** $\;x\neq1\;$" (as then we divide by a non-zero number!), and thus we get

$$\require{cancel}\frac{\cancel{(1-x)}y}{\cancel{1-x}}=\frac{-2x-1}{1-x}\implies y=\frac{-2x-1}{1-x}=\frac{2x+1}{x-1}$$